# HighCharts pointRange trancating width. Is this a HighCharts bug or am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a HighCharts chart that combines a spline and a column. The column data defines a single Y value---indicating a single column---and uses pointRange to indicate what X value range that single column covers. Everything works fine as long as the pointRange is less than the maximum X value in the spline data. But when the pointRange is greater than the maximum X value in the spline data, HighCharts radically truncates the point range, e.g. from my desired 10,000 to about 4200, about half the maximum X value. The label also shifts radically to the left, as if the column has a significant extent for X values less than 0, which do not exist in the data I pass.

(I would like to post a snapshot of the problem, but my reputation is insufficient.)

Is this a HighCharts bug, or am I missing something here? Bayes suggests the latter of course, but I can't fine what I am missing. Hence this request to the gods of stackoverflow.

Here is a fiddle illustrating my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Bridgeland/UVF4P/1/ If you change the pointRange from 10000 to 8000, you can see the result that I expected, albeit with slightly smaller column.

Here's my code, with much of the data omitted for brevity:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'pointRange is too small'
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 1
        },
        xAxis: {
            min: 0
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            data: [
                [0, 1],
                [215, 1],
                // middle of spline data omitted for brevity
                [8189, 0.007198560287942413],
                [8404, 0],
                [8620, 0]
            ],
            type: 'spline',
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            zIndex: 1
        }, {
            data: [0.5],
            type: 'column',
            pointInterval: 10000,
            pointPadding: 0.01,
            groupPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            shadow: false,
            pointPlacement: 'between',
            pointRange: 10000,
            zIndex: 0,
            minPointLength: 3,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                inside: true,
                color: 'white',
                formatter: function () {
                    return 'Misplaced'
                }
            }
        }]
    })
})
```

(And you might be wondering why I have a column chart with a single column? My chart generally has more columns. The single column is a pathological case for a particular combination of data. But despite the pathology, I would still like it to display properly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Highcharts do not permit to have a `pointRange` greater than the max value in `x` or the `minRange` value.

You can fix that by doing :

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'pointRange is too small'
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 1
        },
        xAxis: {
            min: 0,
            minRange: 10000
          //^^^^^^^^^^^
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            data: [
                [0, 1],
                [215, 1],
                // middle of spline data omitted for brevity
                [8189, 0.007198560287942413],
                [8404, 0],
                [8620, 0]
            ],
            type: 'spline',
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            zIndex: 1
        }, {
            data: [0.5],
            type: 'column',
            pointInterval: 10000,
            pointPadding: 0.01,
            groupPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            shadow: false,
            pointPlacement: 'between',
            pointRange: 10000,
            zIndex: 0,
            minPointLength: 3,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                inside: true,
                color: 'white',
                formatter: function () {
                    return 'Misplaced'
                }
            }
        }]
    })
})
```

Since you set `pointInterval` at 10000, I think you can do the same thing with the `minRange` value ?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you also set a xAxis max of, say, 10500? Wouldn't that allow the column to expand to 10k?